# Indri Search Engine - libindri_jni not being created

Tags: java, indri

I am following the instructions here (http://lemur.sourceforge.net/indri/index.html) for installing Indri version 5.7 on my mac. It says about the option of using --enable-java which will produce a lib file called /lib/libindri_jni.so in the install directory. However, after trying many times, even though it installs successfully, libindri_jni.so is never created.

Has anyone faced the same problem before and knows a solution.

thanks in advance,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem while ago and I simply copy and pasted that file in the specified location. To get the complete overview on the details of what I have done, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762274/indri-library-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-change-to-java-lang-noclassdeffoun).